# Problem using js jquery helper

Tags: jquery, cakephp, cakephp-1.3, helper

I am using cakephp 1.3.6 and am trying to use inbuilt js helper. I have added

```
var $helpers = array('Js' => array('Jquery'));
```

in my controller. In my layout, I have included the jquery files and have also included

```
echo $this->Js->writeBuffer();
```

before the `</body>` tag.

I checked if the jquery libraries correctly but trying to create a simple accordian from the jqueryui.com, it works fine.

But when I try

```
<?php
    $this->Js->get('#element');
    $this->Js->drag(array(
        'container' => '#content',
        'start' => 'onStart',
        'drag' => 'onDrag',
        'stop' => 'onStop',
        'snapGrid' => array(10, 10),
        'wrapCallbacks' => false
    ));
?>
<div="element">something</div>
```

It does not work.

I appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I never did see the point in all that nonsense. Just include jQuery the traditional way by writing a  statement by whatever means you prefer - I use something like

`echo $javascript->link('jQuery/jquery-1.3.2');`

Then any javascript, I write as *javascript*.